# Getting 405 error while trying to download nltk data

Tags: python, github, nltk, http-status-code-405

When i try the below code

```
python -c "import nltk; nltk.download('punkt'); 
nltk.download('averaged_perceptron_tagger'); 
nltk.download('maxent_treebank_pos_tagger'); 
nltk.download('wordnet')"
```

the console says

```
[nltk_data] Error loading punkt: HTTP Error 405: Not allowed.
[nltk_data] Error loading averaged_perceptron_tagger: HTTP Error 405:
[nltk_data]     Not allowed.
[nltk_data] Error loading maxent_treebank_pos_tagger: HTTP Error 405:
[nltk_data]     Not allowed.
[nltk_data] Error loading wordnet: HTTP Error 405: Not allowed.
```

Comment: Looks like the download server is down.

Comment: I'm seeing the same problem here so you aren't alone.

Comment: Same problem. I guess we should wait.

Comment: This is caused by a down-age of Github raw file link. Please wait while we find an alternative =)

Comment: We're seeing this throughout OpenDaylight's CI infra https://lists.opendaylight.org/pipermail/dev/2017-July/003971.html

Answer (score 11):

This is caused by a down-age of Github raw file link.

Meanwhile a stop-gap solution would be to manually download the file:

```
PATH_TO_NLTK_DATA=/home/username/nltk_data/
wget https://github.com/nltk/nltk_data/archive/gh-pages.zip
unzip gh-pages.zip
mv nltk_data-gh-pages/ $PATH_TO_NLTK_DATA
```

---

We're working on finding an alternative to the data and model downloading.

Meanwhile, **@everyone please help to check that your script(s) and make sure that you're not overloading the data downloads!** Thank you in advance!!

Please check https://github.com/nltk/nltk/issues/1787 for latest updates on this issue.

Comment: https://github.com/nltk/nltk/issues/1787#issuecomment-318040782 the solution mentioned here worked for me

Answer (score 0):

For MacOSX - small modification to the above answer:

```
PATH_TO_NLTK_DATA=~/nltk_data/
wget https://github.com/nltk/nltk_data/archive/gh-pages.zip
unzip gh-pages.zip
mv nltk_data-gh-pages/packages/ $PATH_TO_NLTK_DATA
```

Note that this is a big download (~700MB).