# What alternative sources can be used for nltk.download()?

Tags: python, nltk

As of 2017-07-26T09:19:35.047715 GMT+1, the link https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nltk/nltk_data/gh-pages/index.xml is down.

The [documentation](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.html?highlight=download#module-nltk.downloader) explains that alterantive sources can be specified but does not provide alternatives.  What are they?

Comment: To which piece of documentation are you referring? A link might help...

Comment: The alternative link to the index e.g. https://pastebin.com/raw/DXBy9WYR won't work too because the Github downage affects not only the index file,  all the .zip packages are down too.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45318066/getting-405-while-trying-to-download-nltk-dta for a temporary solution

Comment: I agree that it is essentially is the same question, and the proposed solution (link) seems to work (I'm doing cloud stuff so I have to wait and see). I would say, IMHO, that this question is phrased more directly to the point which is the missing information.