# HTTP Error 403: Forbidden when using NLTK

Tags: python, nltk

I am trying using nltk in my project and in order to download the nltk data you are supposed to do:

```
>>> import nltk
>>> nltk.download()
```

However, I keep getting the HTTP error 403. I checked online and everyone says to change the default URL to the newest nltk url, but it hasn't worked and I keep getting the error. Any clues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @alvas suggested on this page, this is an easy fix:

```
from nltk.downloader import Downloader
dler = Downloader('https://pastebin.com/raw/D3TBY4Mj')
dler.download()
```

[Getting 405 error while trying to download nltk data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45318066/getting-405-error-while-trying-to-download-nltk-data)

Comment: I'm still getting the same error. I even tried:      python -m nltk.downloader -u https://pastebin.com/raw/D3TBY4Mj punkt

Comment: python -m nltk.downloader -u https://pastebin.com/raw/D3TBY4Mj all  . This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to set proxy like this:

```
nltk.set_proxy('url', 'username', 'password')
```